# My array takes random values despite user input

Tags: c++, arrays, input, random, vector

Excuse me again, I'm not any genius in Programming.

First of all, a summary: array input. Two 3D vectors...ha ha, let's use vectors to calculate MORE vectors. Anyway: dot product is just and plain ridiculous (nine numerals before decimals; I mean, seriously, I didn't ever thought that 1x8+7x5+4x2 could have NINE numerals). Cross product is...even worse.

I made the...uhm...how could I call it? Well, we call it "traza". I'll translate a definition ir order to get understood: *a code's "traza" tell us the sequence of instructions of its execution, and how do the variables change after every line of code*. You know, the table with variables and number marks referred to code lines where we look if the code is doing something unexpected. Getting to the point: it's everything fine as far as I could see.

Then, I made an unexpectedly "pseudotraza" with a print command and every value from the vectors. Just after input and just before te dot product (in a function). Guess what:
1) it's not my input, in either of them
2) they are not even the same values
3) first values are far away from my input, but the following ones at least were more logic (less difference to the input).

I learned this morning, 12 hours ago, to use arrays/vectors/whatever. I didn't ever have any need to set as 0 as default any value before its input. But it's the only thing I have known to do when things like this happened to me before.
(Someday any of you will be my Programming teacher, you are learning me more than himself...and excuse my awful grammar, English teaching in Spain is just "take some grammar rules and no more than 50 exercises in last High School year...it's all you need to pass the University Entrance Exam!")

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>

const int N = 3;
typedef int Vector[N];

void introduirVector (Vector);
float producteEscalar (const Vector, const Vector); /*Input vector and dot product*/

int main (void)
{
 Vector v1, v2;
 float p_esc;

 cout << "Introduim les dades del vector A: "; /* Input */
 introduirVector (v1);

 cout << "Introduim les dades del vector B: "; /* 2x Input combo */
 introduirVector (v2);

 cout << v1[0] << "\n" << v1[1] << "\n" << v1[2] << "\n" << v2[0] << "\n" << v2[1] << "\n" << v2[2] << endl; /* "Puseudotraza*/

 p_esc= producteEscalar (v1, v2); /*Dot product*/

 cout << "El producte escalar: " << p_esc; /*Dot product is...*/

 system ("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}

/*3x Input combo*/
void introduirVector (Vector)
{
    int i;
    Vector v;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
     cin >> v[i];
    }

    return;
}

 /* Dot product (why all the Vectors are set as constants but another after this is not set? It's the hint given by the teacher, my (not) beloved teacher...they gave us the main function and the other function's prototypes, but that's all) */
float producteEscalar (const Vector, const Vector)
{
   float escalar;
   Vector v1, v2;
 /* Pseudotrazas for all*/
   cout << v1[0] << "\n" << v1[1] << "\n" << v1[2] << "\n" << v2[0] << "\n" << v2[1] << "\n" << v2[2] << endl;

/* Dot product and all that */
   escalar = (v1[0]*v2[0])+(v1[1]*v2[1])+(v1[2]*v2[2]);

   return escalar;
}
```

Comment: This question would be a lot more readable if you could reduce the chit-chat to a bare minimum.  Just the facts.

Comment: Also, there's no actual question here that I can see.

Comment: In introduirVector() and producteEscalar(), you're using local variables instead of the data that's passed to the functions.  But then you get to the problem that you're passing by value not reference, so your introduirVector couldn't change the vector passed to it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
/*3x Input combo*/
void introduirVector (Vector)
{
    int i;
    Vector v;
```

This function takes a `Vector` as a parameter, but the Vector has no name so it cannot be used inside the function.

Then you declare a new, *local* `Vector v`. You read your user's input into this vector.

The function then ends, at which point the vector into which you read user input goes away.

Firstly, you should be using the parameter you were called with, not a local variable. But your second problem is that you are using [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449265/function-not-working-as-intended/18449733#18449733). When you call this function, `introduirVector (v1);` it is *not* the "v1" you know and love from main that you are working with inside `introduirVector`, but a *local copy* of it that ceases to exist when your function returns.

What you need to do is make your function accept a pointer or a reference to the Vector it is being called with:

```
void introduirVector(Vector& v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        cin >> v[i];
    }
}
```

This does not fully solve all of the problems with your code, but it should get you moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any input, which would be why you are not receiving any input.

Try using:

```
string inpt;
int a, b, c;
cin >> inpt;
a = atoi( inpt.c_str());
inpt = "";
cin >> inpt;
b = atoi( inpt.c_str());
// etc...

// Make your vector in this fashion, grabbing each integer separately then loading them
// into a vector
```

Comment: The input is in introduirVector().  See the "cin >> v[i];"

Comment: Oh my bad, so the problem is that he is passing a vector, not a pointer to a vector. Which causes the editing of a variable whose scope keeps changing. Rendering it invalid

Comment: That is among the problems yes.  The cin is only to local variables...  The data passed to the functions isn't used.  The data that is passed is passed by value not reference... Etc.

Comment: So its just a terrible, unintelligible mess, and should be ignored?

Comment: Strings haven't been explained yet in my class. I can't use them.

Comment: @NathanWride Generally when faced with a question with this many problems, yes, I tend to just give up, or just give a quick hint in a comment then give up.  The real problem is that time spent on this question won't add value to future readers; it's a specific problem (or series of problems) for a specific user that can't be made more useful to a wider audience...